# Unable to get the anchor tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I wanted to get the name and link from the list of anchor tag inside a section, but I am not able to get it.

URL https://www.snopes.com/collections/new-coronavirus-collection/

[image]

```
category=[]
url=[]
for ul in soup.findAll('a',{"class":"collected-list"}):
    if ul is not None:
        category.append(ul.get_text())
    else:
        category.append("")
    links = ul.findAll('a')
    if links is not None:
        for a in links:
            url.append(a['href'])
```

Earlier, I was able to get the list and URL, but now the website structure is changed, and my code is not working, the expected output is like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like the `a` tag of interest is now `collected-item` not `collected-list` anymore (this is the section class now). You could search for all `a` tags with class name `collected-item`, and under that same anchor find the `h5` tag with class `title` to get the title description wich seems to include (with some manipulation) the category you described in your expected output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.snopes.com/collections/new-coronavirus-collection/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

category=[]
url = []

for ul in soup.findAll('a',{"class":"collected-item"}):
    if ul is not None:
        title = ul.find('h5', {"class": "title"}).get_text()
        title_short = title.replace("The Coronavirus Collection: ","")
        category.append(title_short)
        url.append(ul['href'])

for c,u in zip(category, url):
    print(c,u)
```

```
Origins and Spread https://www.snopes.com/collections/coronavirus-origins-treatments/?collection-id=238235
Prevention and Treatments https://www.snopes.com/collections/coronavirus-collection-prevention-treatments/?collection-id=238235
Prevention and Treatments II https://www.snopes.com/collections/coronavirus-collection-prevention-treatments-2/?collection-id=238235
International Response https://www.snopes.com/collections/coronavirus-international-rumors/?collection-id=238235
US Government Response https://www.snopes.com/collections/coronavirus-government-role/?collection-id=238235
Trump and the Pandemic https://www.snopes.com/collections/coronavirus-collection-trump/?collection-id=238235
Trump and the Pandemic II https://www.snopes.com/collections/coronavirus-collection-trump-2/?collection-id=238235
```